# Variables in Backbone.js routes: regex required?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'd like a Backbone routing setup that works as follows:

- routes like `/country/[any string]`, where `country` is either `us` or `ca`, should both go to `handleByCountry(country, location)`
- any other route should redirect to `/` and be handled by `handleHome`.

Currently I have (as a crude first attempt):

```
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
          "ca/:str": "handleByCountry",
          "us/:str": "handleByCountry",
          "*route": "home" 
      },
      handleByCountry: function(str){
          console.log('ROUTE handleByCountry', route); 
          // how to get the country? parse route by hand?
      },
      home: function(route){
          this.navigate('/');
      },
  });
```

This has the following problems:

- Not DRY - can I write a single route that matches both `ca` and `us`? I need some kind of conditional variable, maybe a regex.
- How can I check the current country from inside `handleByCountry`? Do I need to parse the route string again?

Also, is forwarding other routes to `/`, as I am doing, good practice?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can write single route for ca and us

```
routes: {
    ":country/:str": "handleByCountry",
    "*route": "home" 
},

handleByCountry: function(country, str){

    console.log('country is:', country, ' and str is: ', str, route); 
},
```

We've used similar pattern to redirect all unkown routes to 404 in a same manner as you did with redirecting to home so I believe it's a correct way to do it

If you need more custom routes you can pass custom regular expression as a route instead of backbone route string using the route method in the router initializer.

Comment: close but not quite there, for me at least... i need to restrict `country` to either ca or us but nothing else. is that a job for a regex?

Comment: yeah you need to use the `route` method in the initializer of your router and create a custom route there using regexp - check the documentation for it http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route there is an example with using regexp there